# Is it possible to Insert code into PHP string

Tags: php

I am trying to insert code in a php string dynamically. A simplified example would be:

```
echo "two plus three equals {2+3}"; //the code in the brackets would evaluate to 5
```

I know this can be done easily beforehand with:

```
$var = 2+3;
echo "two plus three equals $var";
```

But is it possible without the extra variable step or using eval?

Comment: You might try sprintf `echo sprintf("two plus three equals %d", 2+3);`

Comment: Is it possible? Sure, but you would need to write your own parser, unless @Thefourthbird's answer is satisfactory.

Comment: It is possible you need to use concatenate those number

Comment: A helper variable `$e="htmlentities";` would allow inline function expressions `echo "two plus three is {$e(2+3)}";`.

Comment: "Code" can mean a lot of things. Are you just referring to simple arithmetic expressions or you want to be able to do anything? `echo 'User with ID {$db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?)")->exec(["jimmy"])->getInsertId()} has been created successfully.'`